# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS ERROR LOCALHOST

Tags: php

In most cases, a plain URL will be recognized as such and automatically linked:
The error only appears on localhost, please help!

The interesting thing is that on the hostinger server it works perfectly...

```
require_once('header.php');


// Preventing the direct access of this page.
if(!isset($_REQUEST['slug']))
{
header('location: index.php');
exit;
}
else
{

// Check the page slug is valid or not.
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_page WHERE page_slug=? AND status=?");
$statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['slug'],'Ativo'));
$total = $statement->rowCount();
if( $total == 0 )
{
    header('location: index.php');
    exit;
}
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_page WHERE page_slug=?");
$statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['slug']));
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
$page_name    = $row['page_name'];
$page_slug    = $row['page_slug'];
$page_content = $row['page_content'];
$page_layout  = $row['page_layout'];
$banner       = $row['banner'];
$status       = $row['status'];
}

// If a page is not Ativo, redirect the user while direct URL press
if($status == 'Inativo')
{
header('location: index.php');
exit;
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the page? Directly? If not, are you passing through `$_REQUEST['slug']`?

Comment: I'm going directly